Ternary plot with python-ternary: unable to set axis label and set axis limits
I am using python-ternary to generate a ternary plot with some of my data.
I have two problems. One rather simple, I guess, and one I can't really understand.
Here below is my piece of code.
import ternary
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data_df['C'] = 1 - (data_df['A']+data_df['B'] )

n = 100
print(data_df[['B','A','C']].head(n).describe())
print(data_df[['B','A','C']].head(n))
data_dictionary2 = data_df[['B','A','C']].head(n).values


#--------------- Setting axis limit in ternary axis ---------------------------
figure, tax = ternary.figure(scale=1)
tax.boundary(linewidth=2.0)
tax.gridlines(multiple=0.1)

# -- set axis limit
tax.set_axis_limits(axis_limits={'b':[0.94,1],'r':[0,0.1],'l':[0.0,0.1]})

#-- convert the data according to new coordinate
pp = tax.convert_coordinates(data_dictionary2)

tax.scatter(pp)

#-- Update the axis ticks
tax.get_ticks_from_axis_limits(multiple=0.1)
tax.set_custom_ticks(multiple=.1, linewidth=1, offset=0.025, tick_formats="%.3f")

tax.get_axes().axis('off')
tax.clear_matplotlib_ticks()

tax.set_title("Ternary plot\n")
fontsize = 12
offset = 0.14
tax.right_corner_label("X", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.top_corner_label("Y", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.left_corner_label("Z", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.left_axis_label("Left label $\\alpha^2$", fontsize=fontsize, offset=offset)
tax.right_axis_label("Right label $\\beta^2$", fontsize=fontsize, offset=offset)
tax.bottom_axis_label("Bottom label $\\Gamma - \\Omega$", fontsize=fontsize, offset=offset)
figure.savefig('test.png')

The data.csv file is here
When I run the code, I get the following output.

that is not far away from what I would like to have.
The first problem is that there are no axis nor corner label. Why are them not printed?
The second problem is with the scaling. If you look at the console output you will see that the max value for the variable C is 0.018, but if I look at the ternary plot  (I presume that it is plotted on left axis), I see that there are some points at 0.03. If my assumption on the left axis is wrong, and actually the third variable is plotted on the right axis, then it goes up to roughly 0.05.
What I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help and support!

For your first question, try removing tax.get_axes().axis('off') from your code and see if the axis titles are back.

It didn't work. It just printed the rectangular matplotlib frame around.

What about changing the offset values, starting with, say, offset = 0.01?

Also didn't work.

Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Your code works for me (with some similar dummy data) and produces visible axis and corner labels.

are you rescaling the axis as well? Are you using other data not mine?  I'm puzzled...

I'm was using exactly your code but with data_dictionary2 containing just three points [[0.02 , 0.01 , 0.97 ], [0.04 , 0.02 , 0.94 ], [0.012, 0.03 , 0.958]] (I'm afraid I don't like downloading random files off the internet!), and viewing the plot in a Jupyter notebook rather than saving the figure.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

1st problem - no axes labels:
You might need to do tax._redraw_labels() before showing or saving the plot. It's a known issue.
2nd problem - scaling:
Your axis limits are impossible: the corner points don't add up to 1 (or whatever scale you have choose). b0 + r1 + l0 must equal scale to be a valid point. Same for b0 + r0 + l1 and b1 + r0 + l0.
The axes are all correct: A is on the right, B on the bottom and C on the left axis. Plotting direction is 'brl' counterclockwise (the default).
The best you can get for your data on a ternary plot with equally scaled axes is:

import ternary
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data_df['C'] = 1 - (data_df['A']+data_df['B'] )
data_dictionary2 = data_df[['B','A','C']].values

#--------------- Setting axis limit in ternary axis ---------------------------
figure, tax = ternary.figure(scale=1)
tax.boundary(linewidth=2.0)
tax.gridlines(multiple=0.1)

# -- set axis limit
tax.set_axis_limits(axis_limits={'b':[0.95 , 1],'r':[0, .05],'l':[0, .05]})

#-- convert the data according to new coordinate
pp = tax.convert_coordinates(data_dictionary2)

tax.scatter(pp)

#-- Update the axis ticks
tax.get_ticks_from_axis_limits(multiple=0.1)
tax.set_custom_ticks(multiple=.1, linewidth=1, offset=0.025, tick_formats="%.3f")

tax.get_axes().axis('off')
tax.clear_matplotlib_ticks()

tax.set_title("Ternary plot\n")
fontsize = 12
offset = 0.14
tax.right_corner_label("B", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.top_corner_label("A", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.left_corner_label("C", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.left_axis_label("⟵ C", fontsize=fontsize, offset=offset)
tax.right_axis_label("⟵ A", fontsize=fontsize, offset=offset)
tax.bottom_axis_label("B ⟶", fontsize=fontsize, offset=offset)

# workaround if labels are not shown
tax._redraw_labels()

figure.savefig('test.png')


Thanks a lot! For the first question, I saw a remark on the github page, but was mentioning MacOS, so I thought it was not affecting me. Shame on me I haven't tried anyhow.
For the second problem, I was not aware about the boundary condition on the triangular corner. I have studied a bit the math behind and now it is all much clearer.
Thanks again!
